# Unable to send array from form - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Okay, I've been struggling with this for a while now and I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. I know this has been asked a couple of times but the answers in the other questions are not quite working on my case. I'm trying to send a specific field as an array to rails to no avail.

The generated html looks like this

```
<input class="form-control" id="groups_header_0_version_number_value" name="groups[header][0][version][number][value]" placeholder="value" type="text">
<input class="form-control" id="groups_header_0_version_creator_value" name="groups[header][0][version][creator][value]" placeholder="value" type="text">

<input class="form-control" id="groups_header_1_version_number_value" name="groups[header][1][version][number][value]" placeholder="value" type="text">
<input class="form-control" id="groups_header_1_version_creator_value" name="groups[header][1][version][creator][value]" placeholder="value" type="text">
```

I want to send the `header` as an array to rails server. When I render `params[:group]` in my controller as `json` I get

```
{  
  "header":{  
    "0":{  
      "version":{  
        "number":{  
          "operator":"\u003c=",
          "value":"34"
        },
        "creator":{  
          "operator":"=",
          "value":"joseph"
        }
      }
    },
    "1":{  
      "version":{  
        "number":{  
          "operator":"\u003c",
          "value":"87"
        },
        "creator":{  
          "operator":"=",
          "value":"john"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I really want is a json structure with `header` as an array like

```
{  
  "header":[  
    {  
      "0":{  
        "version":{  
          "number":{  
            "operator":"\u003c=",
            "value":"34"
          },
          "creator":{  
            "operator":"=",
            "value":"joseph"
          }
        }
      },
      "1":{  
        "version":{  
          "number":{  
            "operator":"\u003c",
            "value":"87"
          },
          "creator":{  
            "operator":"=",
            "value":"john"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How should I correctly name the input boxes to get params sent as above? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to change your name attribute to:

```
<input ... name="groups[header][][0][version][number][value]" ... >
<input ... name="groups[header][][0][version][creator][value]" ... >

<input ... name="groups[header][][1][version][number][value]" ... >
<input ... name="groups[header][][1][version][creator][value]" ... >
```

Notice the extra `[]` after `[header]`

This produces the params

```
"groups"=>{"header"=>
   [
     {
       "0"=>{"version"=>{"number"=>{"value"=>""}, "creator"=>{"value"=>""}}}, 
       "1"=>{"version"=>{"number"=>{"value"=>""}, "creator"=>{"value"=>""}}}
     }
   ]
}
```

which appears to be what you want.